# Pandas read_csv ignore non-conforming lines

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a tsv table from an old school database into Pandas.

The data looks like this:

```
Iron Oxide (FeO)    Fe1O1(cr,l)
T(K)    Cp      S      -[G-H(Tr)]/T   H-H(Tr)   delta-f H   delta-f G   log Kf
0                                                       
100                                                     
200                                                     
298.15  49.915  60.752  60.752         0.       -272.044    -251.429    44.049
300     49.999  61.061  60.753         0.092    -272.025    -251.301    43.755
400     51.840  75.704  62.737         5.187    -271.044    -244.543    31.934
.
.
.
```

The first row I skip.  The second row is an 8 column header (tab delimited).  The next three rows have a number and 10 tabs, and every row after that is 8 fields.  So those three rows are a problem.

If I try to read it in like so:

```
import pandas as pd
FeO = pd.read_csv('JANAF-FeO.txt', skiprows=(0,), delimiter='\t', header=0)
```

Then I get this:

[image]

So instead I can tell pandas to manually skip those three lines:

```
import pandas as pd
FeO = pd.read_csv('JANAF-FeO.txt', skiprows=(0,2,3,4), delimiter='\t', header=0)
```

And it is fine, I get this:

[image]

If I were just reading one file, it would be fine, I would skip those rows and be done.  But there are many files, and some of them have variable numbers of a few lines that have more than 8 columns.  So is there a way to have pandas automatically ignore lines that don't match the header's format?

Comment: If you have a bunch of messy data, pandas can help, but I don't think a custom parser is available for you. You're probably going to have to figure out some heuristics that work to filter/morph the lines into something sane and go from there.

Comment: There have more as 8 columns - is known max number of columns?

Comment: There should be 8 columns always.

Comment: Are possible `NaN` values in data? Or is some column with no `NaN` values?

Comment: Yes, on a few lines there may be missing data or text notes.

Comment: Or is some column with no `NaN` values? Some other as `T(K)` ?

Comment: The header is always correct.  There will be many lines with no NaN values too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108469/discussion-between-jezrael-and-zsg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your issue is with extra tabs hanging out on those odd one-value lines.

Luckily, the sep argument takes regular expressions.  I recreated your dataset the best that I could and got a decent looking df from the following read_csv:

```
ipdb> test = pd.read_csv('test.txt', skiprows=(1), header=(0), sep='\t*')
ipdb> test
 T(K)     Cp        S  -[G-H(Tr)]/T  H-H(Tr)  delta-f H  delta-f G  log Kf
0    0.00     NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN
1  100.00     NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN
2  200.00     NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN
3  298.15  49.915  60.752        60.752    0.100   -272.044   -251.429  44.049
4  300.00  49.999  61.061        60.753    0.092   -272.025   -251.301  43.755
5  400.00  51.840  75.704        62.737    5.187   -271.044   -244.543  31.934
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you need more universal solution, try:

```
#number 15 in range(15) depends of max number of tabs, in my test data 
df1 = pd.read_csv('JANAF-FeO.txt', delimiter='\t', names=(range(15)))

#remove columns with all NaN
df1 = df1.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df1.columns = df1.iloc[1,:]
df1 = df1[2:]

#mask if there are not 7 times NaN in line
mask = df1.isnull().sum(axis=1) != 7
df1 = df1[mask]

print df1
```